# Why postgresql query WAIT for another tab of browser finish first?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I use PHP with PostgreSQL as database.
I found that PostgreSQL do work as synchronous per a single connection.
Therefore, if you have multiple connection, the query of each connection will run in parallel, is this right?

So i've run a test by open 2 tab of browser (Chrome) and run the SELECT query in both tab
(It's about gis data and it takes long time)

In the mean time, i do monitor the postgres activity in command line by running `ps -auwxx`
After send the query of both window, the activity show only single SELECT at a time.
And the result on the webpage return in order correspond to the order of the tab that i hit send.

Should it show 2 process of SELECT? Since two tab should have 2 connections of postgres?

I did test another one by using incognito mode instead of second tab.
The result is as expected, the command line monitoring show 2 process and the faster query show earlier (not wait for the first one to complete first.)

Have i misunderstood anything here?... Could you please explain why it turns out like this?
Any way to make it run parallel?

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using PHP, it might be that you're suffering from session locking. This would mean that although you're loading your site in two different tabs, PHP processes the requests in series, not parallel.

> PHP writes its session data to a file by default. When a request is made to a PHP script that starts the session (session_start()), this session file is locked. What this means is that if your web page makes numerous requests to PHP scripts, for instance, for loading content via Ajax, each request could be locking the session and preventing the other requests from completing.
>
> The other requests will hang on session_start() until the session file is unlocked. This is especially bad if one of your Ajax requests is relatively long-running

From [PHP Session Locks – How to Prevent Blocking Requests](http://konrness.com/php5/how-to-prevent-blocking-php-requests/)